# Name and unit for the amount of electromagnetic radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Is there a name or unit for the amount of electromagnetic radiation? By this, I mean the number of photons, or the number of photons emitted per second, of electromagnetic radiation.

If you were to have two lamps, exactly the same in all ways, they would emit twice as much radiant flux as one lamp. However, this would only be because they're emitting twice as many photons. I need a way to describe this.

Radiant flux and radiant energy are not what I'm looking for, since they relate to energy, and not the number of photons.

Comment: What is wrong with the unit "number of photons per second"? It's probably not going to have a specific name because it doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: Could this be approximated using a lightbulb's wattage and wavelength? If I know that a lightbulb (mostly) emits light at 254 nm and is rated for 2 W, could I convert wavelength to frequency, calculate energy per photon from frequency, and then divide 2 W by that?

Comment: A sub-question of this one: is the brightness perceived by an eye purely do to wavelength (or some other properties of the individual photons that make up light), or additionally due to the number of photons hitting the eye?

Comment: How about photon flux?

Comment: "Flux" is exactly what you want.

Comment: Wavelength is important for the response of the eye.

Comment: That's exactly what I want! If you make that an answer, I'll mark it as correct and upvote it.

Comment: FWIW, a mole of photons is an [einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_(unit)), but use of this unit is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

The photon flux is what you want, but perhaps you would conceptualize why if you also considered the photon fluence, which would be taking the photon flux and integrating it over a unit of time.  Sometimes considering a similar, related definition helps clear up the former.  So compare flux to fluence.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two incandescent light bulbs glowing at the same temperature but one has twice the surface area so emits the same spectrum but twice as many photons per second, then it also emits twice as much energy per second. And vice versa.

Basically you started with the incorrect premise that energy and number of photons jointly vary in a nonlinear fashion. But they don't. So the energy flux is exactly proportional to what you want.

The amount of energy delivered by $N$ photons of frequency $\nu$ is $Nh\nu.$ So the way you get a spectrum exactly the same but with $M$ times the energy is to have $M$ times as many of each kind of photon.

Now if your point is that you wanted to count the number of photons *per se,* without regard for frequency, then you likely have an infinite number since many many low frequency photons can be emitted.

And it gets worse, the emission can be a superposition of different numbers of photons, so there might not even be a preexisting definite number of photons until you measure them all. And the final death blow is that photons themselves are an abstraction about excitations of a free quantum electromagnetic field and the actual quantum electromagnetic field is not free, but interacts with the quantum fields associated with charged elementary particles.

But an average energy per second is a perfectly fine (and finite) measure. That's an excellent thing to talk about.

And if you have a laser of frequency $\nu$ you could take the energy flux and divide by $h\nu$/photon to get the photon flux and it would have photons per blah as the units (where blah is $s$ or $sm^2$ depending on which kind of flux you meant).